# How to retrieve an entity at DTO Projection?

Tags: java, spring-data

I can't retrieve a result set that contains both fields from two entities

I've tried to add a Data Projaction Interface but it retrieves incorrect data

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "common", name = "entity_a")
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

}



@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "common", name = "entity_b")
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String value;

}
```

also i have a `JPARepository` interface

```
public interface EntityARepository extends JpaRepository<EntityA, String> {

    interface EntityAB {
        String getName();
        String getValue();

    }

    @Query("SELECT a.name as name, b.value as value FROM EntityA as a " +
            "INNER JOIN EntityB as b " +
            "ON a.code = b.code " +
            "WHERE a.code = :code")
    Collection<EntityAB> findAllNamesAndValuesByCode(@Param("code") String code);
}
```

IDE shows me that me that getName() method link is correct, but getValue() is never called... I supposed that i need to use some other approach, but i don't know how is it done... So, when i get the result of that query i get a collection of JdkDynamicAopProxy@11111 and so on... I can't operate with this object.

The best for me is to retrieve a link to object `EntityB`, but i cannot get it at my `EntityAB` projection... I think i should use some getter like

```
EntityB getEntityByCode(String code);
```

and implement it in code, but it seems too primitive...
How should i do such an operation?

Comment: It's correct that you get JdkDynamicAopProxy because this is the dynamic implementation of your interface. But what do you mean by "I can't operate with this object"?

Comment: what is the need of inner interface `EntityAB ` ?? return type of `findAllNamesAndValuesByCode()` should be collection of entity, but you kept colletion of `EntityAB`, why? what you are expecting?

Comment: Omg! I thought that my getters, that are declared in EntityAB interface don't work... but after your question i've checked them and everything works as it should!!! Thank you ver much!!! I think i somehow missed to check whether it is a goor query result!

Comment: @TheSprinter i try to retrieve only two fields using custom query from two entities. As i've read at guides, i should use a data projection as an inner interface at my repository... value and name fields are located at separate tables.